# Показать определенный текст из CSV

Tags: xpath

Есть задача -

> из текста на `CSV` взять определённую часть с помощью `XPath`.

Например:

```
<location>
Иркутская область, г. Усолье-Сибирское, Матросова улица, 2
</location>
```

Надо из данного текста вытащить город

> "г. Усолье-Сибирское".

Пробывал написать `/location[last()]` - но это не то-что надо.

Не очень силен в `XPath`.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы вытащить город из текста используйте следующую XPath-конструкцию:

```
substring-before(substring-after(/location, ', '), ', ')
```

Конструкция substring-before() выбирает часть строки до указанной подстроки, а substring-after() - после указанной подстроки. Сначала используется substring-after() с указанием ', ' в качестве подстроки, чтобы вырезать все, что идет до города, а затем substring-before() с тем же указанием, чтобы вырезать все, что идет после города. В результате остается только город.

Например, если использовать эту конструкцию с приведенным выше текстом, то будет выведено:

г. Усолье-Сибирское

Comment: Спасибо большое.